# Quantum physics related to other dimensions

Tags: quantum-spin

Science amateur here so please bare with me.

I just saw this nice video about quantum physics where Julien Bobroff tells about how paired electron's spin is linked through great distances, 11km or more (this is the current experimental maximum).

[video in french sorry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6kg2yV_3B1Q&t=2415s)

Here is what I understood, if two electrons are "linked/paired" their spins are also linked so if you separate them and change one's spin the paired electron's spin will instantly change to match their initial pair state (top/down or down/top)

So this got me thinking could this be linked to another dimension?

Imagine you are in a 2d world on a piece of paper and another 2d dimension intersects with yours, then imagine there is a circle in that other dimension that also intersects with your dimension, you would experience the circle as two dots. However, the two dots would be directly linked by that circle in that other dimension thus changing one might "magically" affect the other.

Could this be the case with electrons and our 3 dimension world?

Are some scientists somewhere working on that theory?

Regards,

Alex

Comment: That would be a type of [non-local hidden variable](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/374266/123208).